# Css hover works on link 3 only in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have 3 links to other pages, but only no3 shows a color change on hover in Safari.
It works fine in Firefox and others but not Safari.

```css
 ul .root-menu li:hover > a {
      color:#FFF;
         }
```

```html
        <div id="menu">
      <ul id="root-menu">
       <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="area_covered.php">AREA COVERED</a></li> 
       <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>    
      </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: It works on my safari 11

Comment: your Safari version?

Answer (score 0):

its a bit complicated when cant see real example of your case, but maybe try to set display: inline-block or block for links

```
ul#root-menu li > a {
    display: block; // or inline-block
}
```

also try to add :hover state styles directly for **a**, but not for **li**:

```
ul#root-menu li > a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

But again, answer would be more accurate if you will show real examle

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Still no joy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - but still no joy. The site is located at: www.altrinchamcarkeys.co.uk  Now non of the menu links are showing a color change on hover.  I have included the css in the body so it can be inspected. Please bear in mind that the problem seems to exist on Safari. I am testing on Safari 11.0.2

Comment: just tested on Safari 10.1.1 and it works fine. Just in case try to clean browser cache